# What is deferred assignment in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, variable-assignment, terminology

In Kotlin Documentation, there is mentioned about deferred assignment

```
val a: Int = 1  // immediate assignment  
val b = 2   // `Int` type is inferred  
val c: Int  // Type required when no initializer is provided  
c = 3       // **deferred assignment**
```

What is the meaning of **deferred assignment**?

Answer (score 10):

This means simply that the variable is initialized not in its declaration but at a later point.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the Documentation the `val c: Int` is declared before `c` is initialized in the following line.

This means you can initialize a non nullable `val` inside a function some lines after you declared it.

For example like this:

```
class Hichhiker {
    fun foo() {
        val firstName: String
        val lastName: String
        val age: Int
        firstName = "Arthur"
        lastName = "Dent"
        age = 40
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
class Hichhiker {
    fun foo() {
        val firstName = "Arthur"
        val lastName = "Dent"
        val age = 40
    }
}
```

So the compiler recognizes the initalization of the non nullable `val` even if the assignment was deferred by some lines of code.

For something similar on the class level and more often used see [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#lateinit-top-level-properties-and-local-variables) and [delegates like lazy()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#standard-delegates)

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the variable has been initialized and the assignment of a value to it takes place lines of code below the initialization.Meaning the assignment has been postponed for later.